# Is it better to put auxiliary helper functions in the controller or in a service that interacts with a Domain Object?

Tags: php, oop, object, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am creating a web application where users can submit different types of content. Currently, processing the content and saving it is done by something like a `ContentService` which further delegates tasks to a `ContentMapper` (for the DataMapper pattern) etc.

As the application is growing, there needs to be other tasks involved with a submission of a `ContentObject`. For instance, there needs to be calls to a `PermissionService` (to determine which users are allowed to view the content), as well as a `NotificationService` (to determine how the users are notified about a new content).

Should I put these auxiliary service (Permission/Notification) calls in the controller or in the service for the goal of creating structured code?

Ie, do I do this:

```
ContentService->createNewContent()
// in ContentService
public function createNewContent($contentObject) {
    // Database calls and other stuff, validation..
    PermissionService->determinePermissionsForContent($contentObject)
    NotificationService->notifyUsers($contentObject)
}
```

or do I put these things (since they are more separate and I'm trying to abide by SRP) into the controller?

ie

```
// in ContentController
$contentObject = // something creates the contentObject from user-data
ContentService->saveNewContent($contentObject)
PermissionService->determinePermissionsForContent($contentObject)
NotificationService->notifyUsers($contentObject)
```

I'm mainly confused because the auxiliary services are essentially run only when the content is saved and they might require certain data (ie the database id)  that's why I'm thinking about them in the ContentService.
On the other hand, if I put them inthe controller, this seems to adhere more to SRP since then ContentService is not doing too many things.

Which is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

The second approach would definitely not make it more-SRP-adherent, since you would need that something to create your `contentObject` (which you tried to gloss over).

> <sub>**Note:** I am not entirely sold on the notion of having a `PermissionService` since permissions are part of the content's "meta-data".</sub>

My approach should be to have two services called from the controller:

```
public function postContent($request)
{
    $contentParams = [
        'title' => $request->getParam('foo'),
        'text' => $request->getParam('bar'),
    ];
    $library->addEntry($contentParams);
    $notifier->sendUpdates();
}
```

.. where first call creates that new content and the second one checks for the newest additions ans sends out the notifications. And there is no point in dragging that `$contentObject` everywhere, since both of them should be interacting with a shared repository.

Bottom line is this: your second approach **is** better, but there is no point in that dangling content object. It looks more to me like you have not figured out how to let your services to share the domain objects.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a shared repository? In your snippet, sendUpdates does not take any parameters, and the notifier depends on information in $contentParams. How would the notifier know about the submitted content?

Comment: No, the notifier depends on whether there are any new entries created. If notifier and library is interacting with the same [repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), then the notifier would care only if there was something new added to it.